# What does it mean to "mark a field as literal" in the world of .NET?

Tags: reflection

According to Microsoft's documentation, `FieldInfo.GetValue(object)` will throw a `NotSupportedException` if:

> "A field is marked literal, but the field does not have one of the
>   accepted literal types."

I have no idea what it means to

> "mark a field as literal."

I want to understand this so that I may know how to guard against this exception.

Comment: Do you mean FieldInfo.GetValue(object) ?

Comment: Yes, thehennyy, I mean FieldInfo.GetValue(object). Thanks for helping me correct my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `literal` is a `const` field. Every const field has its value determined at compile time, by initialization from a literal. Look at this code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;


public class Program
{
    const int literal_int = 5;
    readonly int literal_int_two = 5;
    const string literal_string = "Fun";
    const Random literal_random = null;
    int non_literal;

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo f in typeof(Program).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance 
        | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        | BindingFlags.Static
        | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is literal - {1}", f.Name, f.IsLiteral);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GetValue = {0}", f.GetValue(null));
            }
            catch{}
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
literal_int is literal - True
GetValue = 5
literal_int_two is literal - False
literal_string is literal - True
GetValue = Fun
literal_random is literal - True
GetValue = 
non_literal is literal - False
```

However,

> but the field does not have one of the accepted literal types

is open to interpretation and I couldn't find an example for a literal that doesn't have 'one of the accepted literal types' (whatever that means).

By briefly looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/fieldinfo.cs,8020f5b75134dafc), I couldn't find a relative piece of code to stand for this exception. You should be safe ignoring this clause.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I've been reading StackOverflow for years, but only today have I now become an active participant. I'm amazed how just how quickly and how thoroughly my question has been answered. As a participant, I have a lot to live up to. A +1 for linking to the .Net source code.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`FieldInfo.IsLiteral` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isliteral%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets a value indicating whether the value is written at compile time
> and cannot be changed.
>
> The IsLiteral property is set when the FieldAttributes.Literal
> attribute is set. If this attribute is set, the field cannot be
> changed and is constant.

Comment: Thanks, thehennyy. I now know what it means to "mark a field as literal."

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

The exception stated by

> "A field is marked literal, but the field does not have one of the accepted literal types."

... have to be related to `FieldInfo` instances created by dynamic or custom code (rather than gathered through *Reflection*), where often certain validations are delayed or omitted.

A `FieldInfo` object contains meta-data that represents a field, but its class is inheritable and any derived implementation could potentially allow the bad type condition.